# How to implement OnScrollistener in a fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I can't seem to get to implement/extend OnScrollistener for my recyclerview to know when the recyclerview hits the bottom

```
public class UpcomingFragment extends Fragment
```

How do i implement it if:

```
implements RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
```

and

```
implements OnScrollListener
```

give me an "Interface expected here" error

My build gradle module:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "company.com.movieapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
```

Build grade project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Based on the docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html

`RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` is `abstract`.

### Use the listener like this:

```
private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
        // code
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        // code
    }
};
```

### Add to `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
```

Comment: It says cannot resolve method addOnScrollListener when I try to add it to my RecyclerView

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`. You are using an outdated library.

Comment: @JamesA `app/build.gradle`: should have `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'` dependency

Comment: @karaokyo Yes. The latest is `22.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
    // code
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
    // code
}
};
```

**then add the onScrollListener to the method addOnScrollListener like this**

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
```